# Tracking visitor with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, xmlhttprequest

I have one master domain : www.domain-A.com

I have some domains that call a javascript file on this principal domain.

For example, www.domain-B.com use the file www.domain-A.com/file.js

In this file.js script, I'm trying to put cookie (that's ok) and send some data to www.domain-A.com like the query string, the referrer and the user agent.

I've use that code in my 'file.js' (found on W3School website) :

```
//Envoi des données
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var json = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://www.domaine-A.com/script.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(urlParams + "&" + infParams + "&" + u);
```

It's working very well on FF and Chrome. But, not on IE because I have this error :

```
This page is accessing information not under its control
```

So, I've look a little how analytics send data to Google and i seem's use a GIF or something like that but i don't know how to do it in the good way.

My goal is send data from domain-x.com to domain-a.com with javascript.

Comment: They send it with an image request in the querything. You are making a cross domain ajax call which requires CORS and browsers that support that.

Comment: So? I need to use the "gif" method for do my tracking?

Comment: See http://caniuse.com/cors and then http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

Comment: Basically there is a good reason why google-analytics works the way it does :)

Comment: The only reason why you would use an Ajax call is if you care about the response. Tracking should not give a crap what the server has to say.

Answer (score 0):

What version of GA are you using? If you are on analytics.js (Universal Analtyics) You can use ajax and the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) to call page views on the other site. The measurement protocol lets you make HTTP requests and send raw data right into to GA.

I have used it before to track interaction with interactive infographic that I had on another site.

For your case you can use the following paramaters

```
www.google-analytics.com/collect

v=1             // Version.
&tid=UA-XXXX-Y  // Tracking ID / Web property / Property ID.
&cid=555        // Anonymous Client ID.

&t=pageview     // Pageview hit type.
&dh=mydemo.com  // Document hostname.
&dp=/home       // Page.
&dt=homepage    // Title.
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i think you misunderstood my question. I want to use my own system and my own script :)